# AutoCapitalization of TextField of UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uialertview

I’m popping up a `UIAlertView` with a `UITextField` in it. I want the text field to auto-capitalize all words. I’m doing this by setting properties of the text field, but they have no effect at runtime. Here’s my code:

```
UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: title
                                                message: message
                                              delegate: self
                                      cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles: @"Create", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField* titleField = [alert textFieldAtIndex: 0];
titleField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
[alert show];
```

this autocapitalization is working on `UITextField` form `XIB` but this is not working on UIAlertView ,i am using iOS 6.

Comment: So, if you nslog the value of titleField, none of the words are capitalized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it doesn't change your requirements, using

```
titleField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault;
```

along with

```
titleField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
```

gives you the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "Auto-Capitalization" is enabled in Settings in the iOS Simulator and/or on your test device.

**Settings > General > Keyboard > Auto-Capitalization**

If disabled, it will ignore the `autocapitalizationType` property on your `UIAlertView`'s text field.

Answer (score -1):

You can use uitextfield delegates

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"textFieldDidEndEditing");
    textField.text=[textField.text uppercase];
}
```